# Free portable lightweight app to see time in selected cities, including daylight savings

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec, date-time

I want some recommendations on some free portable lightweight app to see time in selected cities, including daylight savings.

I currently use a Firefox plugin but I want to free it from this so I need a Windows app.

Comment: This should be CW.

Answer (score 1):

[**Microsoft Time Zone**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=bff59fcf-3148-40b8-a286-fe7274f6e4d8&displaylang=en) may be just what you are looking for.  It is free and happily sits in the system tray.

Answer (score 0):

I use Windows Control Panel/Date and Time for simple calculations in different cities.

If you need something that shows time in several cities at once, try [QLock](http://www.qlock.com/) or [Sharp World Clock](http://www.programming.de/).
If you need to see timezones arrangement with the most important cities try this site - [interactive time zones map.](http://24timezones.com/download_world_time_zone_map.php) Unfortunatelly, as far as I could tell, none of them are portable.

Comment: just fyi: Sharp World Clock is a trial version (pay for a key to keep using); dunno if it follows through on the 14-day limit or not.  QLock seems to have a free version but it's hard to tell for sure.

Comment: @~quack - you're right. Mistake on my part. I haven't used any of them myself, so I guess I was a little too quick when checking them out.